# Application in Kotlin/Swift vs Web Application

Tags: android, reactjs, kotlin, web-applications

I'm developing an android application in Kotlin. It is a movie library connected to The Movie Database, where the user can seek for a specific title or just see the tiles in the "Explore" tab. I was discussing with my colleague because he thinks that for this kind of application a web app would be better instead of a native app. The reason why I've chosen to develop it in Kotlin are these:

1. It has some feature which can be available offline, like the watchlist;
2. I have the possibility to create widget for the app which gets integrated in the Android system;
3. I can manage a database locally instead of using an external one;
4. I can customize the design more specifically according to the device where I run it (tablet, phone etc..)

What are other key features which make the develop an app in Kotlin/Swift worthless?
These are some screens of my app:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are looking for other language or framework, you might try `Flutter`, it supports iOS, Android, Web, macOS, Windows.

Comment: @Pemassi I'm looking for reasons why developing in Kotlin would be better than in other language or Framework such as Flutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays a lot can be done to let web apps "behave" just like native apps thanks to Progressive Web Apps (web app manifests, service worker scripts and web APIs).

**(Progressive) Web Apps pros**:

- can be install able (as in having an icon on the home screen and be launched)
- can be used offline (leveraging installed service workers and caching)
- can have splash screens, app icons and so on
- can be written once for multiple platforms (e.g. iOS and Android)
- can be written in JavaScript, CSS, HTML
- can send push notifications (via installed service worker script)
- can run in background (via installed service worker script)
- can have local storage (via IndexedDB and Cache API)
- can use many different Web APIs to use device functionality (e.g. geo location)
- can be shared via URL and can be used without download / installation
- usually much smaller in size
- and many more..

**(Progressive) Web Apps cons:**

- usually not listed in official app stores (this is not impossible however using e.g. Apache Cordova)
- usually not leveraging native ui elements and native ux best practices (can however be done, but it is a trade off when developing for different platforms with a single code base)
- performance might be slightly worse compared to native code
- certain permissions impossible (e.g. reading SMS / contacts)
- certain interfaces can only be used when not in background (e.g. gps or bluetooth)
- specific stuff like Android Widgets needs to be developed separately

**The web app cons listed above are the reasons why it still (might) make sense to develop in native languages like Kotlin or Swift.**

The exact pros and cons however depend on the exact type of web app. There are regular web apps, progressive web apps, hybrid apps and cross platform apps. E.g. when using PhoneGap / Apache Cordova:

> The resulting applications are hybrid, meaning that they are neither
>   truly native mobile application (because all layout rendering is done
>   via Web views instead of the platform's native UI framework) nor
>   purely Web-based (because they are not just Web apps, but are packaged
>   as apps for distribution and have access to native device APIs).